# Search json field with mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid3

I've got the following MongoDB/Mongoid document:

```
#<Event 
  _id: 51e406a91d41c89fa2000002, 
  namespace: :namespace, 
  bucket: "order_created", 
  data: { 
    "order"=>{
      "id"=>100, 
      "deleted_at"=>nil, 
      "created_at"=>2011-10-06 15:45:04 UTC, 
      "updated_at"=>2013-07-10 16:37:07 UTC, 
      "completed_at"=>2013-07-10 16:37:07 UTC
    }
  }>
```

Here is the event class definition:

```
class Event
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :namespace, type: Symbol
  field :bucket, type: String
  field :data, type: Hash
end
```

I want to find and update it using the [find_and_modify method](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/querying.html#find_and_modify) in Mongoid but I can't figure out how to properly structure the search criteria to search the data field properly.

Specifically, I want to find `data.order.id = 100`. I've tried the following with no luck:

```
Event.where(:data.order.id => 100)
Event.where(:'data["order"]["id"]' => 100)
Event.where( { data: { order: { id: 100 } } } )
Event.where( { data: { :"order" => { :"id" => 100 } } }
```

The latter returns nil, but the former (and, from the documentation I've read, the correct way to do it) gives me a `SyntaxError: unexpected ':'`.

This is with Mongoid 3.1.4 and MongoDB 2.4.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question. The Event class is not referencing a collection, which is what's critical for the Criteria search to work. I've instantiated a new db object to use against the collection and the find/where methods work. Here's an example:

```
@db = Mongoid::Sessions.default
@db[:events].find().first['order']
@db[:events].where("data.order.id" => 100).first
```